# Clicking on MenuItem without clicking on the text

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

I've got a Menu, and I want to click on the menu, but not on the text if you guys know what i mean.
The MenuItem has a border, or something like this, but when I click on it it won't redirect to the page I want unless I click on text.

Is it possible to click on the whole "Button" and redirect or do what is need to do?

My menu is like this:

```
<rich:dropDownMenu showDelay="250" hideDelay="0" submitMode="none">
        <f:facet name="label">Tools</f:facet>

        <rich:menuItem>
            <s:link view="/pages/tools/ppaParameters/PpaParametersEdit.xhtml" value="Parameters" id="PpaParametersId" includePageParams="false" propagation="none"/>
        </rich:menuItem>

        <rich:menuGroup value="Security">
            <rich:menuItem>
                <s:link view="/pages/tools/security/ppaModule/PpaModuleEdit.xhtml" value="Module" id="PpaModuleId" includePageParams="false" propagation="none" />
            </rich:menuItem>
        </rich:menuGroup>
</rich:dropDownMenu>
```

There's an example. I need to click on text to make it work out.

[image]

Comment: When you are editing a .doc file, you'll have a menu with "File", "Edit", "View", "Help", etc..
When you click on it, you got some options, but you don't have to click on the text "Save" to save your document, you can click anywhere on the button to select save button and it will save anyway. Still don't get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style the menu item using:

```
display:block;
```

---

For example, for a `rich:menuItem` using `h:link` (instead of `s:link`, but same idea should apply):

```
<rich:menuItem immediate="true">
    <h:link value="System" outcome="menu-01" id="menu-01" styleClass="menu-item-link" />
</rich:menuItem>
```

Within the CSS, change the menu item label class (`.rf-ddm-itm-lbl`):

```
/* Allow clicking anywhere on a menu item, not just the text. */
.rf-ddm-itm-lbl {
    display: block;
}

/* Style the menu to taste. */    
a.menu-item-link {
    color: #333333 !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    display: block !important;
}

/* Remove space for icons. */
.rf-ddm-emptyIcon, .rf-ddm-emptyIcon {
    display: none;
}
```

Note the two instances of `display: block;`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not perfect but could work. 
You can use something like this:

```
 <rich:menuItem onclick="location.href='url'">
     <h:outputText value="Link 2" />
 </rich:menuItem>
```

This will allow you to click anywhere inside the menu item.

url - you will have to put it yourself and add all the request parameters that s:link adds. For example:
http://server/app/page.seam?cid=XX&propogate=xx...

If you need the conversation id, you can use: `<s:conversationId>`

Hope this helps...

Comment: one problem, we're using s:link cause it is not working properly when I use menuItem.. do you know anything that I can do to work it out still with s:link?

Comment: No, I never used s:link inside menu item. s:link renders a GET response, as a workaround just put together that response string yourself.

Comment: I dont know about s:link, but I used a4j:commandLink and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Either give the text css selector the same height and width as its parent. Or give the button the behavior you're giving the text.